# i18n/UTF-8 character string issue with itext java

Tags: java, json, unicode, utf-8, itext

i am creating pdf with itext from the data i recieve in json. it may content any language characters in i18n/UTF-8.

i gone through the itext examples which shows how to display i18n/UTF-8 characters usinh unicode. but in my case i need to take string from json and directly put it to pdf.

in this case i am getting junk chracters in pdf. i have use Unicode font Arial_Unicode_MS.

[image: itext pdf displaying junk chars for UTF-8 language characters]

Is there any way to do this write?

```
data=record.getString(dbColNames[j]);

if (data == null || data.equalsIgnoreCase("null") || data.equalsIgnoreCase("")
    data = "N/A";
dataCell= new PdfPCell(new Phrase(8, new Chunk(data, dataFont)));
dataCell.setBackgroundColor(color);
pdfTable.addCell(dataCell);


{
    "5mintime_org": "2014-10-20",
    "rrank": "2",
    "maxutq_org": "47.73",
    "avgutq_org": "7.92",
    "username_org": "صارف",
    "username": "صارف",
    "5mintime": "2014-10-20",
    "rrank_org": "2",
    "maxutq": "47.73",
    "avgutq": "7.92"
},
{
    "5mintime_org": "2014-10-16",
    "rrank": "3",
    "maxutq_org": "43.75",
    "avgutq_org": "6.32",
    "username_org": "用户",
    "username": "用户",
    "5mintime": "2014-10-16",
    "rrank_org": "3",
    "maxutq": "43.75",
    "avgutq": "6.32"
},
```

Comment: how do you take string from json?

Comment: json.getString("key") i even tried json.getString("key").getBytes("UTF-8") but no luck.

Comment: Please show the code you use to inject those strings

Comment: I removed pdf as a tag and added json. I'm 99% sure that iText nor PDF are causing the problem. I'm pretty sure that you do not receive the bytes as an `UTF-8` String. Fix the data I/O and your problem will be solved.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Lowagie I/O was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the proper of reading json data. Your editor encoding may not support utf-8 while compiling or interpreting. I suggest that you read the json data from a file that supports Utf-8 encoding and change the default locale as well.